# animejs timeline for multiple items of the same class

Tags: javascript, animation, anime.js

I'm trying to use animejs timeline (relative) to display one item after the other has finished. I've followed what they've shown as the example - http://animejs.com/documentation/#relativeOffset but surely this could be done in a much cleaner manner?

I was trying to figure out how to do it using foreach, but I can't seem to get it working. This is what I have, which works, but it's clearly messy, and long, and won't allow for any more items than 5 (or less for that matter).

```
var relativeOffset = anime.timeline();
        relativeOffset.add({
            targets:'ul > li:nth-child(1)',
            easing:'easeInOutSine',
            translateY:-25,
            duration:300,
            delay:1800,
            opacity:{
                value:[0,1],
                easing:'linear'
            }
        }).add({
            targets:'ul > li:nth-child(2)',
            easing:'easeInOutSine',
            translateY:-25,
            duration:300,
            opacity:{
                value:[0,1],
                easing:'linear'
            },
            offset:'+=50'
        }).add({
            targets:'ul > li:nth-child(3)',
            easing:'easeInOutSine',
            translateY:-25,
            duration:300,
            opacity:{
                value:[0,1],
                easing:'linear'
            },
            offset:'+=50'
        }).add({
            targets:'ul > li:nth-child(4)',
            easing:'easeInOutSine',
            translateY:-25,
            duration:300,
            opacity:{
                value:[0,1],
                easing:'linear'
            },
            offset:'+=50'
        }).add({
            targets:'ul > li:nth-child(5)',
            easing:'easeInOutSine',
            translateY:-25,
            duration:300,
            opacity:{
                value:[0,1],
                easing:'linear'
            },
            offset:'+=50'
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `.add` is chainable, you can use a little recursion magic to get what you want while still incrementing the `nth-child` selector (which I believe is the only property changing from one transition to the next - correct me if wrong)

```
const initRelativeOffset = anime.timeline();

const addTransition = (relativeOffset, i = 1) => {
    if(i <= 5) { // keep adding the transition until i passes 5 (you could always change this number if you want to add more <li>s
        addTransition(
            relativeOffset.add({
                targets: `ul > li:nth-child(${i})`,
                easing:'easeInOutSine',
                translateY:-25,
                duration:300,
                delay:1800,
                opacity:{
                    value:[0,1],
                    easing:'linear'
                }
            }),
            i + 1
        )
    }
}

addTransition(initRelativeOffset)
```

This should work, but if it doesn't, it'd help if you could update your post with a little more context, such as the HTML structure

Comment: Thanks for that, I've taken what you've done and made my own changes to get it to do what I want it to do, just needed a push in the right direction :)